# Finding the index of the first gap in a sequence of numbers

Tags: c#

I have a problem. It's a bit difficult to explain, but I am going to try. I have a few buttons, which I want to give a sequence. I created a dictionary with the buttons and the `SequenceNum`. Now when I am in the sequence select screen, I can click a button and give it a number. Now I have this code for getting the next highest number:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SelectedHexagonRegistryObject> row in SelectedHexagonRegistry.ToList())
{
    if (row.Value.SequenceNum >= NextSequenceNum)
    {
        NextSequenceNum = row.Value.SequenceNum + 1;
    }
}
```

Now SequenceNum does always get the next highest number, but there is a problem with this. When I gave for example 6 buttons a sequence number and I click 3 again, it gets reset. That is supposed to happen, but when I want to swap numbers for example, I also click the button with the SequenceNum 4. There are 2 buttons with no sequence numbers. If I click one of the 2 buttons that don't have sequence number. The next number is 7. But the problem is that there is a gap, because the numbers 3 and 4 are reset, so I want to be the next number the lowest number of the gap. How can I create something like that?

**Example:**
I have 6 buttons, which I want to give a sequence number.
When I click the first button it will get SequenceNum 1
Then when I click the rest it will get the highest given number + 1.
At the end I have 6 buttons with all a sequence number from 1 to 6.
When I click for example the button with SequenceNum=4 again, I can unset the SequenceNum to 0 (equals `null`).

Now when I click that same button another timen, I want it to get the number of the gap that I created, so SequenceNum 4. 
Now the problem is that it gets number 7, because it takes the highest + 1.
I need code to fill the gaps and I can't seem to figure out how I can make that!

Comment: You could also simply do `SelectedHexagonRegistry.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.SequenceNum).Max()` to get the max value. But you are not actually searching for the maximum number, what you want is to sort the values ascending and find the first gap, as you've explained yourself.

Comment: Okay thanks, that is easier.... But thats not my problem!

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code that's giving you a problem..?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, its more a logical problem. I can create gabs when I unselect a button. Those gabs doesn't get filled, because it takes the max number + 1. But in my example I unselected button 3 and 4. But when I select them again, they get number 7 and 8. I need to fill the gabs!

Comment: Remember we have no idea what this looks like, or what *"when I click 3 again"* means, or what a `gab` is.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk by "gabs" you mean "gaps"? The problem is that you have a set of numbers and you need to find the lowest gap (missing number) in the sequence or, if there is no gap, the next number in the sequence. Is that correct?

Comment: @Matt Burland, yeah sorry... My bad!

Comment: You have to post enough code for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will add some explanation about my problem in my question

Comment: You also refer to a `SelectedHexagonRegistryObject` object, which is not a `Button`. Please help us help you by either defining what these things are or using common objects that we all understand (which would be best).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, unless I am mistaken:

```
static int GetNextSequenceNo(Dictionary<string, SelectedHexagonRegistryObject> registry)
{
    // order the values ascending
    var vals = registry.Values.OrderBy(s => s.SequenceNum).ToList();

    // find the first value where .SequenceNum is different from (idx + 1)
    var firstGap = vals.TakeWhile((s, idx) => s.SequenceNum == idx + 1).Count();

    // take the sequenceNum from the previous item and increment
    if (firstGap > 0)
        return vals[firstGap - 1].SequenceNum + 1;
    else
        return 1;            
}
```

Comment: Still same problem. When I have a gap, it just moves on to 7!?
firstGap is always 0!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: can you clarify? I just [tested it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X3sCFR) and it seems ok, perhaps I didn't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: When I click a button it needs to get number 1. Then when I click the next it needs to get number 2, etc. But when I unselect and select again, I want it to fill the gap with the number of the gap, instead of a new highest number

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: have you checked the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X3sCFR)? First three calls to `AddNext` in this example generate numbers 1, 2 and 3. Then after 2 is removed, next call returns 2 again.

Comment: Just to make sure, when I say there is a gap. I mean that I have set the number to 0. Because 0 doesn't play a role, maybe that's our misunderstanding, because you remove the whole number from the dictionary, but I can't do that... The dictionary line contains more important information, and I can't set the number to `null`, because that gives me the error: Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type

Comment: Ok, that clarifies the issue. The simplest solution would be to remove the value from the dictionary, similar to what is shown in the example, instead of setting it to zero. If for some reason you really think you need to keep the item in the collection, but set its sequence number to zero, then either use a `List<SelectedHexagonRegistryObject>`, or remove the zeros from the dictionary first (`var vals = registry.Values.Where(v => v.SequenceNum != 0).OrderBy(s => s.SequenceNum).ToList();`).

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: yes, I've tested it with zeros and it's ok: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pD1h8b).

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a list of integers and you want to find the next lowest available number, you can sort them (if they aren't already sorted) and then walk the list one item at a time, comparing the current item to the next item. As soon as you find one where the next item is greater than the current item by more than 1, you have found a gap and can return `currentItem + 1`.

If you get to the end of the list, then you just return the next number.  For example:

```
private static int GetNextAvailableNumber(IReadOnlyCollection<int> numberSequence)
{
    // If the list is null or empty, return the first number (this uses 1, modify as needed)
    if (numberSequence == null || !numberSequence.Any()) return 1;

    var orderedNumbers = numberSequence.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < orderedNumbers.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var thisNumber = orderedNumbers[i];
        var nextNumber = orderedNumbers[i + 1];

        if (nextNumber - thisNumber > 1) return thisNumber + 1;
    }

    return orderedNumbers.Last() + 1;
}
```